# C# : Forcing a clean run in a long running SQL reader loop?

Tags: c#, sql, garbage-collection, sqldatareader

I have a SQL data reader that reads 2 columns from a sql db table.
once it has done its bit it then starts again selecting another 2 columns.

I would pull the whole lot in one go but that presents a whole other set of challenges.

My problem is that the table contains a large amount of data (some 3 million rows or so) which makes working with the entire set a bit of a problem.

I'm trying to validate the field values so i'm pulling the ID column then one of the other cols and running each value in the column through a validation pipeline where the results are stored in another database.

My problem is that when the reader hits the end of handlin one column I need to force it to immediately clean up every little block of ram used as this process uses about 700MB and it has about 200 columns to go through.

Without a full Garbage Collect I will definately run out of ram.

Anyone got any ideas how I can do this?

I'm using lots of small reusable objects, my thought was that I could just call GC.Collect() on the end of each read cycle and that would flush everything out, unfortunately that isn't happening for some reason.

Ok i hope this fits but here's the method in question ...

```
void AnalyseTable(string ObjectName, string TableName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Initialising analysis process for SF object \"" + ObjectName + "\"");
    Console.WriteLine("   The data being used is in table [" + TableName + "]");
    // get some helpful stuff from the databases
    SQLcols = Target.GetData("SELECT Column_Name, Is_Nullable, Data_Type, Character_Maximum_Length FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '" + TableName + "'");
    SFcols = SchemaSource.GetData("SELECT * FROM [" + ObjectName + "Fields]");
    PickLists = SchemaSource.GetData("SELECT * FROM [" + ObjectName + "PickLists]");

    // get the table definition
    DataTable resultBatch = new DataTable();
    resultBatch.TableName = TableName;
    int counter = 0;

    foreach (DataRow Column in SQLcols.Rows)
    {
        if (Column["Column_Name"].ToString().ToLower() != "id")
            resultBatch.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Column["Column_Name"].ToString(), typeof(bool)));
        else
            resultBatch.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
    }
    // create the validation results table
    //SchemaSource.CreateTable(resultBatch, "ValidationResults_");
    // cache the id's from the source table in the validation table
    //CacheIDColumn(TableName);

    // validate the source table
    // iterate through each sql column
    foreach (DataRow Column in SQLcols.Rows)
    {
        // we do this here to save making this call a lot more later
        string colName = Column["Column_Name"].ToString().ToLower();
        // id col is only used to identify records not in validation
        if (colName != "id")
        {
            // prepare to process
            counter = 0;
            resultBatch.Rows.Clear();
            resultBatch.Columns.Clear();
            resultBatch.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
            resultBatch.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(colName, typeof(bool)));

            // identify matching SF col
            foreach (DataRow SFDefinition in SFcols.Rows)
            {
                // case insensitive compare on the col name to ensure we have a match ...
                if (SFDefinition["Name"].ToString().ToLower() == colName)
                {
                    // select the id column and the column data to validate (current column data)
                    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, [" + colName + "] FROM [" + TableName + "]", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AnalysisTarget"].ConnectionString)))
                    {
                        com.Connection.Open();
                        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

                        Console.WriteLine("   Validating column \"" + colName + "\"");
                        // foreach row in the given object dataset 
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            // create a new validation result row
                            DataRow result = resultBatch.NewRow();
                            bool hasFailed = false;
                            // validate it
                            object vResult = ValidateFieldValue(SFDefinition, reader[Column["Column_Name"].ToString()]);
                            // if we have the relevant col definition lets decide how to validate this value ...
                            result[colName] = vResult;

                            if (vResult is bool)
                            {
                                // if it's deemed to have failed validation mark it as such
                                if (!(bool)vResult)
                                    hasFailed = true;
                            }

                            // no point in adding rows we can't trace
                            if (reader["id"] != DBNull.Value && reader["id"] != null)
                            {
                                // add the failed row to the result set
                                if (hasFailed)
                                {
                                    result["id"] = reader["id"];
                                    resultBatch.Rows.Add(result);
                                }
                            }

                            // submit to db in batches of 200
                            if (resultBatch.Rows.Count > 199)
                            {
                                counter += resultBatch.Rows.Count;
                                Console.Write("   Result batch completed,");
                                SchemaSource.Update(resultBatch, "ValidationResults_");
                                Console.WriteLine("      committed " + counter.ToString() + " fails to the database so far.");
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop-1);
                                resultBatch.Rows.Clear();
                            }
                        }
                        // get rid of these likely very heavy objects
                        reader.Close();
                        reader.Dispose();
                        com.Connection.Close();
                        com.Dispose();
                        // ensure .Net does a full cleanup because we will need the resources.
                        GC.Collect();

                        if (resultBatch.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            counter += resultBatch.Rows.Count;
                            Console.WriteLine("   All batches for column complete,");
                            SchemaSource.Update(resultBatch, "ValidationResults_");
                            Console.WriteLine("      committed " + counter.ToString() + " fails to the database.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("   Completed processing column \"" + colName + "\"");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Object processing complete.");
}
```

Comment: Why can't you run the validation in SQL Server?

Comment: The validation goes through a process involving some complex rules that cannot be implemented in SQL. Values may be set based on values in other db's possibly even on other networks.

Comment: It seems that this is not an easy one to solve ... for now i'm running this code on a machine with more ram, i did get it a bit cleaner but it still pushes my ram usage to 4.5GB and I haven't tried it on a big table yet (got one that contains about 90 million records).

Answer (score 3):

Could you post some code? .NET's data reader is supposed to be a 'fire-hose' that is stingy on RAM unless, as Freddy suggests, your column-data values are large. How long does this validation+DB write take?

In general, if a GC is needed and can be done, it will be done. I may sound like a broken record but if you have to GC.Collect() something else is wrong.

Comment: +1 I agree, forcing a garbage collect seems plain wrong in this scenario. Besides, without the sequential access the reader will keep internal references to the instances the OP intends to be freed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[Open the reader with Sequential access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=VS.100).aspx), it might give you the behavior you need. Also, assuming that's a blob, you might also be better off by reading it in chunks.

> Provides a way for the DataReader to handle rows that contain columns with large binary values. Rather than loading the entire row, SequentialAccess enables the DataReader to load data as a stream. You can then use the GetBytes or GetChars method to specify a byte location to start the read operation, and a limited buffer size for the data being returned.
>
> When you specify SequentialAccess, you are required to read from the columns in the order they are returned, although you are not required to read each column. Once you have read past a location in the returned stream of data, data at or before that location can no longer be read from the DataReader. When using the OleDbDataReader, you can reread the current column value until reading past it. When using the SqlDataReader, you can read a column value can only once.

Comment: i'm not having issues with the size of the data in a single field, just the sheer amount of fields i need to read.